# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'settings.keyValue.charCodeAt')

Tags: php, javascript

Mi proyecto de laravel de pronto empezó a lanzar el siguiente error,

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'settings.keyValue.charCodeAt')
```

cada que presiono una tecla lanza el error en el archivo `injected.entry.js`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 no recuerdo que modificación pudo haberlo causado.

Comment: puedes poner el ejemplo del codigo?, no solo la imagen

Comment: y esto parece simple javascript, ni php ni laravel

Comment: estimado gracias por su comentario, este fue lo ultimo que coloque `@push('scripts')

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            lan = $('#lectura_anterior').val();
            lac = $('#lectura_actual').val();
        });
        $('#form_lectura').submit(function () {

            if (lac < lan) {
                alert('Lectura incorrecta');
                return false;
            } else {
                alert('lectura OK');
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        });
    </script>
    @endpush`

Comment: pero todo el proyecto funciona bien, los formularios todo, solo que si muestro la consola aparece el error que mencione en la pregunta.. :(